# Pandas for two dataframes calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and want to do some calculation within the dataframe. But I cannot get the result I want. Please check my script.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.3], 'B': [7,8,9,10,11,12], 'C': ['k','k','k','j','j','j']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,1,2,3], 'B': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'C': ['k','k','k','j','j','j']})

df3=df1[df1['C']=='k']['A'].add(df2[df2['C']=='k']['A'][-1:], fill_value=0)
```

When I check df3, I got:

> Block quote

```
0 0.1
1 0.2
2 3.3
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

> Block quote

Actually, I want every data in df1 column A with column C is “k” plus the last one data in df2 column A with column C is “k”. However, now only the last one data in df1 column A did the addition and column B and C gone.

Anyone who knows how to achieve my goals? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df3 = df1[df1['C']=='k']['A']+df2[df2['C']=='k']['A'].iloc[-1:].iloc[0]`

yields:

```
0    3.1
1    3.2
2    3.3
```

In the code above, I am extracting the last value in `df2[df2['C']=='k']['A']`, *i.e.* 3.0 and adding it to all rows in `df1[df1['C']=='k']['A']`

**[EDIT]**  To answer your question in the comments section below, you can save the B and C columns from df1 in a separate dataframe (*e.g.* df4) and then concatenate them back with df3:

```
df4 = df1[df1['C']=='k'][['B','C']]
df5 = pd.concat([df3,df4],axis=1)
```

Which yields:

```
     A  B  C
0  3.1  7  k
1  3.2  8  k
2  3.3  9  k
```

The resulting df5 dataframe can then be concatenated with a dataframe containing the rows of df1 for which the value in column C is not equal to k:

```
df6 = df1[df1['C']!='k']
df7 = pd.concat([df5,df6])
```

Which yields:

```
     A   B  C
0  3.1   7  k
1  3.2   8  k
2  3.3   9  k
3  0.1  10  j
4  0.2  11  j
5  0.3  12  j
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I only want to change these 3 values and keep the others in df1 ( column B and C and A with df1[‘C’]=‘j’). How to achieve this?

Comment: Hi CHENLU! I have edited my answer to address this new question.

Comment: is there any in-situ replace way to get the same result? It seems to be a little complicated that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.3], 'B': [7,8,9,10,11,12], 'C': ['k','k','k','j','j','j']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,1,2,3], 'B': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'C': ['k','k','k','j','j','j']})

df1 = df1[df1.C == 'k'].A
df2 = df2[df2.C == 'k'].A
df1.add(df2)
```

The above code results in:

```
0    1.1
1    2.2
2    3.3
Name: A, dtype: float64

pd.concat([df1[df1['C']=='k']['A'], df2[df2['C']=='k']['A']])

The above line results in

0    0.1
1    0.2
2    0.3
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
```

Comment: The result I want is `3.1 3.2 3.3`. That is every item in df1 add 3 in df2.

Answer (score 0):

Not clearly understand your goal. My understanding is that you want to calculate the values in df1 column A and the values in df2 column A, which the values in both columns are in the same position with `k` in column C.

```
df3=(df1[df1['C']=='k']['A']) + (df2[df2['C']=='k']['A'])

Output:
0    1.1
1    2.2
2    3.3
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sorry, what I want is 3.1, 3.2, 3.3. Every item in df1 column A add the last one (3) of df2 column A.